# jquery remove() with multiple form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a single section  in a form. I have multiple forms with the same  sections. When I am in MyForm1 in Split3 and trigger the remove, only Split3 in MyForm1 should be removed not all.

Any suggestions using for example:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title> test</title>  
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>  
  <style type='text/css'>
    form {
    font-family: helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
}

form div{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

form a {
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
    background: #555555;
    color:#f7f7f7;
    text-decoration:none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
  </style>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form[name="inpForm"]').submit( function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest("form");
        alert($(this).find('input[name="FirstName"]').val());
        alert("name of form: " + $form.attr('name'))
        alert("div index: " + $(this).closest("div").attr('id'));
        return false;
    });

    $('.removeSplit_2_').click(function(){
        var numItems = $('div').length;
        alert("Aantal div secties: "+ numItems);
        $('div').each(function(){
            var indexDiv = $(this).attr('id');
            alert("div index: " + indexDiv); // or simple this.id
            if (numItems == indexDiv) {
                alert('Do your thing and remove the div section');
                //$(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });

    $('.removeSplit_3_').click(function(){
        var MijnID      = this.id;
        alert(MijnID);
        var numItems = $('div').length;
        alert("Aantal div secties: "+ numItems);
        $('div').each(function(){
            var indexDiv = $(this).attr('id');
            alert("div index: " + indexDiv); // or simple this.id
            if (numItems == indexDiv) {
                alert('Do your thing and remove the div section');
                //$(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
});//]]>  

</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name = "MyForm1">
    <div id="Split1">MyForm1 Split1
        <input name="FirstName" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="Split2">MyForm1 Split2
        <div name="cButton_2_" id="cButton_2_" class="cButton_2_" ><input name="FirstName" type="text"/></div>
        <div name="xButton_2_" id="xButton_2_" class="xButton_2_" ><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeSplit_2_" class="removeSplit_2_"><IMG SRC="./1x.gif" BORDER="0"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Split3">MyForm1 Split3
        <div name="cButton_3_" id="cButton_3_" class="cButton_3_"><input name="FirstName" type="text"/></div>
        <div name="xButton_3_" id="xButton_3_" class="xButton_3_"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeSplit_3_" class="removeSplit_3_"><IMG SRC="./1x.gif" BORDER="0"></a></div>
    </div>
</form>
<form name = "MyForm2">
    <div id="Split1">MyForm2 Split1
        <input name="FirstName" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="Split2">MyForm2 Split2
        <div name="cButton_2_" id="cButton_2_" class="cButton_2_"><input name="FirstName" type="text"/></div>
        <div name="xButton_2_" id="xButton_2_" class="xButton_2_"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeSplit_2_" class="removeSplit_2_"><IMG SRC="./1x.gif" BORDER="0"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Split3">MyForm2 Split3
        <div name="cButton_3_" id="cButton_3_" class="cButton_3_"><input name="FirstName" type="text"/></div>
        <div name="xButton_3_" id="xButton_3_" class="xButton_3_"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeSplit_3_" class="removeSplit_3_"><IMG SRC="./1x.gif" BORDER="0"></a></div>
    </div>
</form>
<form name = "MyForm3">
    <div id="Split1">MyForm3 Split1
        <input name="FirstName" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div id="Split2">MyForm3 Split2
        <div name="cButton_2_" id="cButton_2_" class="cButton_2_"><input name="FirstName" type="text"/></div>
        <div name="xButton_2_" id="xButton_2_" class="xButton_2_"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeSplit_2_" class="removeSplit_2_"><IMG SRC="./1x.gif" BORDER="0"></a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="Split3">MyForm3 Split3
        <div name="cButton_3_" id="cButton_3_" class="cButton_3_"><input name="FirstName" type="text"/></div>
        <div name="xButton_3_" id="xButton_3_" class="xButton_3_"><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="removeSplit_3_" class="removeSplit_3_"><IMG SRC="./1x.gif" BORDER="0"></a></div>
    </div>    
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I use:
`$('.removeSplit_2_').click(function () {
var mySplit  = $('.Split_2_');
mySplit.remove();});`

all slpits2 will be removed.

When I use:

`$('.removeSplit_2_').click(function () {
var mySplit;
var form       = $(this).closest("form").attr('id');
var formObj    = document.getElementByIdform); 
//mySplit   = $('.Split_2_'); not working
mySplit        =  $( form ).find( 'Split_2_'); 
//mySplit.remove(); also not working
 $( "div" ).remove( mySplit );});` this resulte in nothing is removed

Answer (score 0):

So all you need to do is this:

```
$( "#Split3" ).remove();
```

It will grab the first id with the name "Split3" and remove it!

I hope thats what you are looking for.

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/kibipoxowa

Luca

Comment: it will remove all split3 not ony in the form it is in.

Comment: @CyrilleHeltzel No... If you look at the JSBin it proves that it removes only the first one....

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, Try this:

```
$('.removeSplit_2_').click(function () {
    var mySplit = $(this).closest('.Split_2_');
    mySplit.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on( "click", "a", function() {
   $( this ).remove();
});
```

test this